# Mailgun : sending image(HTML) and text from Parse shows only html

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, mailgun

this is the code I used

```
  Parse.Cloud.define("blendedBookMailToUser", function(request, response) {
           var Mailgun = require('mailgun');
           Mailgun.initialize('SandBoxCode', 'Key');

  Mailgun.sendEmail({
  to: "someone@gmail.com",
  from: "me@me.com",
  subject: "Session Booked",
  text: "HIIIIIIIIIIII" ,
  html:'<html><body style="text-align:center;"><img border="0" src="' + request.params.qrUrlKey + '" width="200" height="200" ></body></html>',

}, {
  success: function(httpResponse) {
    console.log(httpResponse);
    response.success("Email sent!");
  },
  error: function(httpResponse) {
    console.error(httpResponse);
    response.error("Uh oh, something went wrong");
  }
});
                   });
```

I receive the mail but only with the html part - so i can see only the image without the text..
If I remove the html part I receive the text.

how can I combine them? and is there a better way to include image?

Using ios and Parse cloud code.

Comment: This is the recieved mail original view:--33cd9261657a412cb62ef49d3b376c2e
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="ascii"
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

HIIIIIIIIIIII

--33cd9261657a412cb62ef49d3b376c2e
Content-Type: text/html; charset="ascii"
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<html><body style="text-align:center;"><img border="0" src="http://files.parsetfss.com/f07ad0f6-e28d-4d62-83d5-69fadc127bab/tfss-5b6b08f7-ead2-4364-bc2b-1c6a4d817079-qr.jpeg" width="200" height="200" ></body></html>     - the text is there somewhere - but i cant see it on gmail...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text represents the text version of the email, where as HTML represents the HTML version of the email.

In order to view the text, incorporate the text within your html version of the email.

Example:

```
var textMessage = "some text message";

Mailgun.sendEmail({
  to: "someone@gmail.com",
  from: "me@me.com",
  subject: "Session Booked",
  text: textMessage ,
  html:'<html><body style="text-align:center;"><img border="0" src="' + request.params.qrUrlKey + '" width="200" height="200" >' + textMessage + '</body></html>',

}, {
  success: function(httpResponse) {
    console.log(httpResponse);
    response.success("Email sent!");
  },
  error: function(httpResponse) {
    console.error(httpResponse);
    response.error("Uh oh, something went wrong");
  }
});
```

This should place the text message below your image.